# Display additional User details in Custom List

Tags: user-profile, list-view, custom-list

I have a custom list definition based upon a content type which includes a field of type "User".

When I display this field in my list view, it shows the name with a link to the entry in the site collection user information list.

I would like to have additional user information displayed in the view, taken from the user's profile, including things like Position and Organisation. Is there any way to acheive this through changes to the List's `Schema.xml`?

If this is not possible, is there a way I can do it by over-riding the display of the User field for particular lists to include additonal information? Possibly with XSL?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column with user info and duplicate info there every time you add/edit list item. If info you want to display is not changed frequently, this could be your choice.

Or you can do your own web part to achieve this.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, it's a hacky work-around (and not a particularly good one, as it wouldn't stay up-to-date as changes happen in AD/UPS).

Comment: If you use webpart, it will be always up to date and you can display any info you want.